# I am trying to deploy helloworld web services but after running URL i am getting error

Tags: java, xml, web-services, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy helloworld web services but after running URL i am getting error:-
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.And i am using below URL to get the output:-http://localhost:8080/Ticket/rs/test/hi .I have already set the server to tomcat 9.0 and changed the properties also

```
**package practice.ws; 
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    @Path("/test")
    public class Test {

        @GET
        @Path("/hi")
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String sayHi()
        {
            return "Hey! i am working fine ";
        }

    }

Web.xml Code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>practice.ws</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Your application file should be "Tickets.war". The context path (first part of URL) is derived from the filename. So if your filename is "Tickets-1.0.0-snapshot.war", then the URL must be http://localhost:8080/Tickets-1.0.0-snapshot/rs/test/hi

When you deploy an application via Tomcats management website (http://localhost:8080/manager/html), you can specify a different context name for the application.

Additional possibilities to change the context path are documented there: https://octopus.com/blog/defining-tomcat-context-paths

Comment: Then try to enable more log messages and check them. Your Jax-WS should log helpful messages during initialization. Next time please be more precise when you write that something is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Now It is resolved , i got the URL output , Web service successfully deployed, in web.xml 
in servlet-class i have entered the wrong servlet container